# Sheets function working in standalone Google Script but NOT when script is bound to a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have this piece of code that is working perfectly when I use it in a standalone Google Script running as a web-app :

```
function getSubjectsRollNosFromGradeSheet() {
  var spreadsheetId = '171hWWH8bV6kM1JJ2dvL80q3BoWC6eEc0U7l7wCTaXHE';
  var rangeSubject = 'GradesT1!G1:AA1';

  var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, rangeSubject).values;
```

However when I write this same code in a Script that is embedded inside another Google sheet (not the one being accessed for data) attached to a Google Form I get an error :

```
function updateForm(){

  // call your form and connect to the drop-down item
  var form = FormApp.openById("1VV_LeFJODZcIzfcYOh8vHEkhl033Lx4ZsXaY4Pm1ZUE");
  var subList1 = form.getItemById("497738674").asListItem();

  //pull data from another sheet
  var spreadSheetID = "1EJSx62rZuLSKIgel7LH8hE7-68lupz4buutmVQBqi2I";
  var rangeSubs = 'Sheet1!A1:A';

  var subValues = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetID, rangeSubs).values;
```

I get this error

> ReferenceError: "Sheets" is not defined. (line 16, file "Code")

Why is the Sheets object available in the first case but not in the second case and how should I change my code to overcome this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sheets` is one of methods of Advanced Google Services. So in order to use `Sheets` of Advanced Google Services, please enable Sheets API for Advanced Google Services and API console as follows.

Please do this at the bound script which included the script of your question.

#### Enable Sheets API v4 at Advanced Google Services

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Advanced Google Services
  - Turn on Google Sheets API v4
  - Enable Sheets API v4 at API console

#### Enable Sheets API v4 at API console

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Cloud Platform project
  - View API console
  - At Getting started, click Enable APIs and get credentials like keys.
  - At left side, click Library.
  - At Search for APIs & services, input "sheets". And click Google Sheets API.
  - Click Enable button.

#### References :

- Advanced Google Services : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced
- Sheets API v4: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Yes. This solves the problem. Stupid of me to have missed this.

Comment: @Calcutta I'm glad I could help. At recent update of Google, Manifests was added to Google Apps Script. By using this, Advanced Google Services can be also enabled by json. The detail information is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests).